# Dynamic Layer Name - Leaflet Layer Control

Tags: javascript, controls, leaflet, layer

I would like to have the name of a layer used by Leaflets **layer control** feature come from a variable instead of a string and based on data from the layer.

The example shown below uses the variable layerName. Is this even possible since it is expecting a name value pair? Is there a work around?

```
var layerName = feature.properties.condition[0];

//layer control
var baseMaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": OSM,
    "Aerial Imagery": MapQuestOpen_Aerial
};

var overlayMaps = {
    layerName: layer1,

};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, of course you can use the layer name from a variable based on layer data.

Here is the way you should adopt

```
var overlayMaps = {};// you need to create it empty at first
```

Then you can add layers to it like below

```
overlayMaps[layerName] = layer1; //layerName here is the variable whose value you want to use as layer name
```